# vertical align middle in <div>

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I want to keep the height of `#abc` `div` at `50px` and text to align vertically in the middle of the `div`.

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#main{
  position: relative;
  background-color:blue;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}

#abc{
  font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align:left;
  background-color:#0F0;
  height:50px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
 <div id="abc">
     asdfasdfafasdfasdf
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 206, accepted):

You can use `line-height: 50px;`, you won't need `vertical-align: middle;` there.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/79x2a/25/)

---

The above will fail if you've multiple lines, so in that case you can wrap your text using `span` and than use `display: table-cell;` and `display: table;` along with `vertical-align: middle;`, also don't forget to use `width: 100%;` for `#abc`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/79x2a/26/)

```
#abc{
  font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align:left;
  background-color:#0F0;
  height:50px;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#abc span {
  vertical-align:middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

---

Another solution I can think of here is to use `transform` property with `translateY()` where `Y` obviously stands for Y Axis. It's pretty straight forward... All you need to do is set the elements position to `absolute` and later position `50%` from the `top` and translate from it's axis with negative `-50%`

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/h1emdttc/)

Note that this won't be supported on older browsers, for example IE8, but you can make IE9 and other older browser versions of Chrome and Firefox by using `-ms, -moz` and `-webkit` prefixes respectively.

For more information on `transform`, you can refer [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

Comment: this does not work if you have long text

Comment: magicly works for me w/ transform way @@

Answer (score 119):

Old question but **nowadays** [CSS3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) makes vertical alignment really **simple**!

Just add to `#abc` the following css:

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
```

[Simple Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mjgjj85v/2/)

Original question demo [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/79x2a/2608/)

Simple Example:

```css
.vertical-align-content {
  background-color:#f18c16;
  height:150px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  /* Uncomment next line to get horizontal align also */
  /* justify-content:center; */
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-align-content">
  Hodor!
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest also:
  display:grid;
  align-items:center;

It works better when you have more than one object to align vertically together

Comment: Which browsers ***supports*** `CSS3` ?

Comment: @Kiquenet, 92% of the global market https://caniuse.com/#search=align-items

Comment: This works very well, thank you. Some of the other posts have not aged well here, and I would suggest implementing this instead of using a heavier hand as some of the other approaches do.

Answer (score 98):

It's simple: give the parent div this:

```
display: table;
```

and give the child div(s) this:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

That's it!

```css
.parent{
    display: table;
}
.child{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Test
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Test Test Test <br/> Test Test Test
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Test Test Test <br/> Test Test Test <br/> Test Test Test
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: this is bad as this is using table as a hack, it may work for most cases, but when you want to change the width of the  'table' , then it's not gonna work properly(which i am having the issue now with this solution)

Comment: I didn't need to add the `display:table;`to the parent to make it work.

Comment: Perhaps this is a hack ... but it WORKS, and most other solutions work only in specific cases and are often not usable in our case.

Comment: Advantage of this solution : works with all type of contents (not only for text, and not only a single line ...)

Answer (score 49):

I found this solution by Sebastian Ekström. It's quick, dirty, and works really well. Even if you don't know the parent's height:

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Read the full article [here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/).

Comment: This might blur things because the result of transforms can be lead to things being positioned at half pixel locations.

Comment: There is an update on the post targeting that issue. On parent: `transform-style: preserve-3d;`!

Answer (score 11):

```css
 div {
    height:200px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: green;
}

.text-align-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-align-center"> Align center</div>
```

Comment: Explain it please!

Comment: `align-items: center` only align the text vertically, but not horizontally. `justify-content: center` does the trick. That `.text-align-center` is the exact 3 lines of code you need to align element to the middle div. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Line height a big as height of the div.
But for me best solution is this --> `position:relative; top:50%; transform:translate(0,50%);`

Answer (score 4):

How about adding `line-height` ?

```
#abc{
  font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align:left;
  background-color:#0F0;
  height:50px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height: 45px;
}
```

[Fiddle, line-height](http://jsfiddle.net/79x2a/28/)

Or `padding` on `#abc`. [This is the result with padding](http://jsfiddle.net/79x2a/29/)

**Update**

Add in your css :

```
#abc img{
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[The result](http://jsfiddle.net/79x2a/33/). Hope this what you looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.main_div{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.cells {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Another method for centering a div:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>

#parent {position: relative;}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This Code Is for Vertical Middle and Horizontal Center Align without specify fixed height:

```css
.parent-class-name {
  position: relative;
}

.className {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.container { 
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid green; 
}

.center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<h2>Centering Div inside Div, horizontally and vertically without table</h2>
<p>1. Positioning and the transform property to vertically and horizontally center</p>
<p>2. CSS Layout - Horizontal & Vertical Align</p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
    <p>I am vertically and horizontally centered.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the translateY CSS property to vertically center your text in it's container

```
<style>
.centertext{

    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(40%);

}
</style>
```

And then apply it to your containing DIV

```
  <div class="centertext">
        <font style="color:white; font-size:20px;">   Your Text Here </font>
  </div>
```

Adjust the translateY percentage to suit your needs. Hope this helps