# Having problems vertically and horizontally centering div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm having a little trouble centering a div both horizontally and vertically. I've had a quick look around and can't really make much sense of other answers, so I thought I would post my own question.

What I am looking to do is center my div with text horizontally and vertically however I need the container div to stay perfectly sized to the window.

Here is the css I'm having trouble with.

```
body{margin:0 auto;}

div#section1 {height: 100vh;background: black;}
```

Also, here's a link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xB84z/), I couldn't post HTML in here for some reason, the "Post" button would grey out.

Thanks

Comment: You are using `vh` so for that reason I'll reopen your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

same: use `vertical-align: middle`.

```
body {
    margin:0 auto;
    color:white;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
div#section1 {
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/xB84z/1/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate your help!

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to add another section beneath this one? Exactly the same, just you have to scroll down to see it.

Comment: I'd like to have multiple sections beneath each other. Whenever I add content after this div/section it appears on the right of this one and I would like it to appear below it, if that makes sense?

Comment: @Viroe yeah it is happening because of `display: table-cell`. Let me check the issue. I am quite busy here right now.

Comment: @Viroe I am not able to get your required layout with `display: table-cell`. So, I used transform which supports IE9+. go with this solution if you don't care about support in IE8. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/xB84z/10/). Hey IE8 doesn't support `vh` unit. So, I am presuming you can go with this :)

Comment: That's great! Thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to use the block of code below with `margin: auto;` which is *important* there.. Rest, playing with CSS positioning will do the job for you.

I don't think there's much to explain here, just make sure you use `position: relative;` for the container element so that your `absolute` positioned element stays correctly

```
div#section1 {
    height: 20vh;
    background: black;
    width: 20vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xB84z/5/)

You can refer [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649106/div-vertical-align-middle-css) here which will explain you some other techniques to achieve vertical alignment, because horizontal is quiet easy using `margin: auto;`

Comment: cool technique, I wasn't aware of this. this made me surprised. :)