# Align image and text in a collapsible jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using an image instead of an icon for my collapsible. What i want is that the text should align center to the image. Right now it is appearing like this `|_` with underscore as the text and `'|'` as the image. I want it to be like this: `|-`

Here is my code:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
    <h4><img src="today_calendar.png" style="height: 80px;"> Today's Events </h4>
```

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649106/div-vertical-align-middle-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bA37f/)**