# Centering Text in Middle of Div

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to center a time inside a div.  I know I am controlling it with inline css.  Can do either I suppose.

Basically just trying to align text align in middle of div - vertical-align: middle; - did not work. Image is current look - u can see it is off...

[image: current look]

Thoughts?

```
  <div style="top: 50%; position: relative; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt; color: green; height: 30px; border-top:1px solid ##000;">
  7:45 am
  </div>
```

Comment: Try the answer posted here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `line-height` style equal to `height`:

```css
div {
  font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt; 
  color: green; 
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>7:45 am</div>
```

Comment: yep worked: <div style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt; color: green; line-height: 30px; height: 30px; border-top:1px solid black; text-align:center;">

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this thread?

[div vertical align middle css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649106/div-vertical-align-middle-css)

Maybe it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `text-align:center`

http://jsfiddle.net/Lybfn4ph/

```
  <div style="top: 50%; position: relative; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt; color: green; height: 30px; border:1px solid black;text-align:center;">
   7:45 am
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be

```
<div style="top: 50%; position: relative; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt; color: green; height: 30px; border:1px solid black; text-align:center;">
7:45 am
</div>
```