# How to vertically center content in before or after in CSS

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, pseudo-element

I'm currently having some troubles making a redesign of Bootstrap alerts. I don't think it's is relative to *Font Awesome*, neither to *Bootstrap*.

The idea is to get a left side on a block with an icon added in the *before*. It works but **the icon is not vertically centered**. It become even much uglier when the right side contains multiple lines.

In two images :

**This is what I get**
[image]

**This is what I want**
[image]

Run the code snippet to see what I achieve so far.

```css
.alert {
  position: relative;
  background: #3498db;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 120px;
  text-align: left;
}

.alert:before {
  content: "\f129";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: block;
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100%; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #34495e;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="alert">
  <p>
    Intellectum est enim mihi quidem in multis, et maxime in me ipso.<br /> 
    Ille quidem fructum omnis ante actae vitae hodierno die maximum cepit, cum summo consensu senatus.<br />
    Ex quo profecto intellegis quanta in dato beneficio sit laus.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `line-height` CSS property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [div vertical align middle css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649106/div-vertical-align-middle-css)

Comment: `line-height` won't work here as the height of the container is unknown.

Comment: is not duplicate because handling the `:before` is different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `display: table;` and `table-cell` works with vertical align property.

```css
.alert {
  background: #3498db;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  display: table; /* Display table */
  width: 100%;
}
.alert:before {
  content: "\f129";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: table-cell; /* Display Table-Cell */
  width: 100px;
  background: #34495e;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.alert > p {
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="alert">
  <p>
    Intellectum est enim mihi quidem in multis, et maxime in me ipso.
    <br />Ille quidem fructum omnis ante actae vitae hodierno die maximum cepit, cum summo consensu senatus.
    <br />Ex quo profecto intellegis quanta in dato beneficio sit laus.
  </p>
</div>
```