# CSS vertical alignement for hover text

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I make some adjustments in quite an old Wordpress website.
We want to add text in circles which previously had single line.

What would be the best way to **vertically align** text in the middle?
I tried it with css for the divs as described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649106/vertical-align-middle-in-div).
But unfortunately it is not responsive.

I would really appreaciate the help!

Comment: Hello, we need a bit more details, HTML structure etc...

Comment: You can try to use `flexbox` it's easy and for you problem it's quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `flexbox` it's easy and for you problem it's quick solution.
Look at this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) it may help you out a lot.

quick use, **CSS:**

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```